# Regex: match the two closest strings only if there's a specific string between them

Tags: regex

So, I'm trying to edit a dictionary file with regex.
My current regex can match the two closest strings (and everything between them). The problem is that I need to find only those strings that have a particular string between them. I tried to combine negative lookahead and positive lookahead, but without success.

Here's my current regex:

```
<b>(?:(?!<\/?b>).)*?<\/b>(?:(?!<\/?b>).)*?<font color=darkslategray>.*?<\/font>
```

An example with a small part of the dictionary file: https://regex101.com/r/yV1zC3/1

And I need to capture the closest occurrences of `<b> </b>` and `<font color=darkslategray> </font>` tags, but only if there are `<VR> </VR>` tags between them. The result should be:

```
<b>na·ive</b><br><div style="padding-left:0.5em;">(<VR><span style="color:#006400;font-style:italic">or</span>  <b>na·ïve</b></VR>) <font color=darkslategray>/nɑˈiːv, naıˈiːv/</font>
<b>na·ïve·té</b> (<VR><span style="color:#006400;font-style:italic">also</span>  <b>na·ive·te</b> <span style="color:#006400;font-style:italic">or</span>  <b>na·ive·té</b></VR>) <font color=darkslategray>/nɑˌiːvˈteı, naıˌiːvˈteı/</font>
<b>na·ive·ty</b> (<VR><span style="color:#006400;font-style:italic">also</span>  <b>na·ïve·ty</b></VR>) <font color=darkslategray>/nɑˈiːvəti, naıˈiːvəti/</font>
```

Is it even possible to do with regex?

Comment: [don't parse html using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/633183)

Comment: But you're not matching `<VR` anywhere. [See your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ5aR7/2) and also use `s` flag if you expect the dot to match newlines too.

Comment: @bobble bubble, yes, in my example there's no mention of <VR>, because all my attempts to combine negative and positive lookahead have failed (although it seems that using positive lookahead was superfluous). So the example shows only the working part - matching the closest strings. I've had a look at your regex and it works as it should. Thank you!